# I am trying to get all domains that contain a certain string to no avail

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dns, facebook-fql

I am trying to get all domains that contain a certain string to no avail.

I tried

```
fql?q=SELECT url, id, type, site FROM object_url WHERE strpos(url,'a') >=0
```

and getting :

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql ", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

I tried

```
fql?q=SELECT domain_name FROM domain WHERE strpos(domain_name,'a') >=0
```

And I am getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "You must specify a domain_id or a domain_name", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

In graph api there is no option for search type domain or url only pages. I need to get domains from FB

First which table should I query domain or object_url?

Comment: Facebook has deliberately hobbled their API so you can't scrape it like this. You have to find the target urls you want another way, then query it `WHERE [url/domain] IN (URI1, URI2, ... URIn)`

Comment: Correct - cpilko you should probably add this as the answer - the documentation for the FQL tables the OP is using explicitly mention you can only query when specifying the domain already